# Nokia Treasure Tag Bluetooth Low Energy Protocol

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, nokia, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to develop an app using Nokia Treasure Tag but since there's very little documentation on this device, I'm having a really hard time with the development.

The app works on Bluetooth low energy, So where a in traditional BLE device you have to enable all the characteristics when you connect with the device, the Nokia Treasure Tag stores the config files and other details and it won't even connect to other smartphones.

Has anyone done any development with Nokia TreasureTag ?
Is there any documentation on this device ?

ThankYou,